# Sich auf den Rücken drehen / wälzen

Tags: phrase

Wenn ich lese, jemand "dreht sich auf den Rücken", kommt mir das stilistisch ungeschickt vor. Unter "drehen" verstehe ich eine Rotation auf der Stelle. Wenn man "sich auf den Rücken dreht", dann rollt man ja aber zur Seite. Man rotiert nicht (wie ein Braten am Spieß), sondern rollt oder *wälzt* sich auf den Rücken.

Dennoch benutzen Autoren und Übersetzer die Wendung "sich auf den Rücken drehen" sehr viel häufiger ([20200 Treffer](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22drehte%20sich%20auf%20den%20R%C3%BCcken%22) bei Google Books), als die Wendung "sich auf den Rücken wälzen" ([3920 Treffer](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22w%C3%A4lzte%20sich%20auf%20den%20R%C3%BCcken%22)).

Hat "wälzen" einen Bedeutungsaspekt (z.B. "schwerfällig"), der Schreibende dieses Wort vermeiden lässt?

Comment: Na klar, @IQV, das scheint in der Regel aber nicht gemeint, wenn ich mir die Beispiele bei Google Books so anschaue.

Comment: Ich kann mir schlecht einen durchtrainierten Hochleistungssportler vorstellen, der sich "auf den Rücken wälzt" - Ein Nilpferd schon.

Comment: "drehen" hat den Vorzug, dass es einen neutralen Affekt vermittelt. Eine Maus kann sich ebenso drehen wie ein Nilpferd, ein Jiu-Jitsu-Kämpfer oder ein Planet. Aber "wälzen" kann sich nur ein grosser oder schwerer Körper, und diese Konnotation ist bei einem menschlichen Schläfer seltener erwünscht.

Comment: @tofro Wenn der durchtrainierte Hochleistungssportler sich im Schlaf bewegt, dann ist sein muskelbepackter Körper aufgrund der Müdigkeit des Schlafenden womöglich ebenso träge und schwer, wie der des unsportlichen Fettwansts. Und dann wälzt er sich im Schlaf so wie unsereins. Denke ich.

Comment: "Sich im Schlaf herumwälzen" und "sich auf den Rücken wälzen" ist aber was vollkommen anderes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deine Vermutung ist korrekt.

#### [wälzen](https://dwds.de/wb/w%C3%A4lzen)

Nach den [Grimms hat **wälzen**](https://dwds.de/wb/dwb/w%C3%A4lzen) noch im Mittelhochdeutsch hauptsächlich die Bedeutung einer Drehung durch Hin- und Herbewegung auf einer Unterlage. Von daher stammt z.B. auch noch die heutige Bedeutung, dass wir in der Küche das Bratgut im Mehl *wälzen*.

Im Neuhochdeutsch ist aber eine zusätzliche Bedeutung hinzugekommen. Wir verstehen heute nämlich unter [wälzen](https://dwds.de/wb/w%C3%A4lzen) auch das Drehen von etwas Großem oder Schweren:

> Er wälzte den Stein zur Seite.
> Sie wälzten den Verletzten auf den Rücken.

Diese Schwere kommt auch zum Ausdruck, wenn wir sagen:

> Ich wälzte mich aus dem Bett.
> Vom Alptraum geplagt, wälzte ich mich hin- und her.

#### [drehen](https://dwds.de/wb/drehen)

Anders beim [**Drehen**](https://dwds.de/wb/drehen), das schon im Althochdeutsch eine gewisse Leichtigkeit hat. Das englische *throw* (werfen) hat die selbe etymologische Wurzel! *Drehen* findet also seine Verwendung beim Flechten oder bei drehenden Maschinen.

Somit ist es auch kein Wunder, dass man, um den Eindruck eines Schwergewichts zu vermeiden, sich viel lieber im Bett *dreht*, als sich dort zu *wälzen*.

Beides hätte sonst aber die gleiche Bedeutung.

Answer (score 3):

> Unter „drehen“ verstehe ich eine Rotation auf der Stelle. Wenn man „sich auf den Rücken dreht“, dann rollt man ja aber zur Seite.

Diese Vorstellung ist nicht ganz korrekt. Eine Drehung ist zunächst einmal eine Kreis- oder Bogenbewegung um einen Punkt oder eine Achse. Dabei ist es irrelevant, ob die Achse an derselben Stelle verbleibt oder verschoben wird.

Es folgt: Wenn sich jemand auf den Rücken dreht, rotiert er um seine eigene Körperachse, bis er mit dem Rücken auf irgendeiner Stelle, die nicht zwangsläufig dieselbe wie zuvor sein muss, zum Liegen kommt.

Anders sieht das beim Wälzen aus. Das ist nämlich eine Rotation, bei der die Achse verschoben wird. Der Begriff *wälzen* ist demnach spezifischer als *rotieren* (bzw. *sich drehen*).

Answer (score 0):

Vielleicht als interessanter Zusatz: In der [Geometrie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulersche_Winkel) bezeichnet man den von Dir angesprochenen Vorgang als "rollen" (d.h. eine Drehung um die Blickrichtungsachse bei geradem Blick voraus).

In der Tat wird die Redewendung "rollte sich auf den Rücken" in dem von Dir gewählten Maßstab bei google Books doppelt so häufig benutzt wie "wälzte..."

Warum nun "drehen" häufiger als "rollen" benutzt wird? Evtl. zur Vermeidung von Missverständnissen, gegeben der weiteren Bedeutung von "rollen" hinsichtlich einer rollenden Bewegung vorwärts á la "die Kugel ist weggerollt".